# how to avoid the ID name in css file

Tags: html, css

is there any efficient way to scan the `id & class` name in css file? there are many css file in my web app and now i have to add some more css file. I often get stuck to define the ID & Class name which is already defined in another css file and it causes problem during testing.
I am really tired of keep changing the id & class name. can some one give me any tips to sort it out.

@Edit : suppose there are two css files in a web app `old_1.css & old_2.css`

```
old_1.css  #id_1 {width:100%;height:100%; ....  }
          #id_2 { width:50%; height:50%; .... }  

old_2.css   #id_3 {width:70%;height:70%; ....  }
          #id_4 { width:30%; height:30%; .... }
```

Now i am creating a new css file `new_1.css` and by mistake i wrote the simmilar id of old css file. this is where i get stuck and i want to avoid to rewrite the same ID.

```
new_1.css  #id_1 {width:80%;height:80%; ....  } // this id is already declared in old css file
```

Comment: Open the project in a good text editor and do a global find?

Comment: Could you explain your problem more clearly? I'm having difficulty understanding what issue you're having...

Comment: I think what he is trying to say is that he needs some kind of tool or script to tell him what classes and ID's are already present in the CSS files so that if he makes a new it does not collide with something already present.

Comment: @Joesavage1 : please take a look, i explained in details.

Comment: @ Cheesebaron : yes you got my point. do u know any tool

Comment: @Cheesebaron With good CSS structure this shouldn't be an issue anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than ensuring each CSS class name is unique, ensure that the CSS styles cannot clash by including parent elements in your CSS. This is better for structure:

HTML:

```
<div class="section1">
    <div class="inner_div">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="section2">
    <div class="inner_div">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.section1 {

}
    .section1 .inner_div {
         color:red;
    }

.section2 {

}
    .section2 .inner_div {
         color:blue;
    }
```

This will ensure that only `div`'s with `inner_div` class will be given the style `color:red` where they are contained in a `div` with the class `section1`. Likewise, only `div`'s with `inner_div` will be styled `color:blue` where they are contained in a `div` with the class `section2`.

Using this format should prevent you from ever having duplicate class names as you can define as far as you like, for example if I was applying a style to a span tag displaying the date for a news article I'd use:

```
.main_container .news .article .details span.date {}
```

This is a lot easier to read, and a lot less likely to be duplicated than:

```
.news_article_date {}
```

---

Otherwise, like @Ant has stated, use a good HTML editor software and do a Find on the classes and IDs used.

Comment: yes, exactly the same way i have written the css structure. but get warning/error sometimes when id clashes.

Comment: :class name is not the issue, but id does sometimes. if i suppose inner_div is an ID in your example then do you think will it work? document.getElementId("inner_div");

Comment: If you have clashing IDs then this is more of an issue with your HTML design. I personally would recommend using classes over IDs for styling unless theres a specific need for it

Comment: yeah, i prefer to use class over id but I have to play with js function so i need to declare the id. anyway thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

If refactoring the old CSS files are beyond the current scope of your work, you can simply override the old styles by making your selectors more specific. A good tutorial on CSS specificity is given [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)